# CSS Custom fonts not showing

Tags: html, css

I have also tried the .ttf version of this font without any results. For some reason the font is not showing up. The url to the font is correct.

```
@font-face {
font-family: EagleLake; /*a name to be used later*/
src: url('EagleLake.otf'); /*URL to font*/
}


h1{
font-family: EagleLake;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this format instead, it definitely works:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: EagleLake;
    src: url(EagleLake.otf);
}
```

Your h1 style attribution should then be of font EagleLake.

Comment: Can you create a JS fiddle and show us what you are doing?